# How can I pass a variable to a URL?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to send an email with a link in the body that contains a value retrieved from Firebase. I am successfully retrieving the value but I do not know how to append it to the link that is already listed.
Here is the code:

```
sendinvite() {
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      var uid = user.uid;

      firebase.database().ref('/userlist/' + uid + '/' + 'hashKey').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
        var hashKey = (snapshot.val());
        console.log(hashKey)
      });

      var bcc = [];
      for(var e in this.emailinputs){
        if (this.emailinputs[e].email==null || this.emailinputs[e].email=="" || !this.emailinputs[e].email.includes("@") || !this.emailinputs[e].email.includes("."))
        {
          let alert = this.alerCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error!',
            message: 'There was an error with an email address you entered.',
            buttons: ['Ok']
          });
          alert.present()
        }else {
          bcc.push(this.emailinputs[e].email);
        }
      }
      if(bcc.length > 0) {
        let email = {
          bcc: bcc,
          subject: 'Nudget Invite',
          body: '<a href="https://nudget-72ee4.firebaseapp.com/?hashkey='+hashKey+'">Join my grocery list!</a>',
          isHtml: true
        };
        this.emailComposer.open(email);
      }
}
```

I want the variable `hashKey` to be appended to the URL listed in the body but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

**Edit 1**

Updated the body to append the variable to the string. I'm not sure where I can place the hashkey from Firebase for it to be referenced properly.

Comment: Have you tried using a standard query string? For example: `https://nudget-72ee4.firebaseapp.com/?key=value`

Comment: @Tigger I currently have `'<a href="https://nudget-72ee4.firebaseapp.com/?hashkey='+hashKey+'">Join my grocery list!</a>'`. The problem is that I don't know where I can place the hashKey variable for it to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see is that you are scoping the 'hashkey' variable to just the firebase...function(snapshot) block.  This should be defined at the top near the 'uid' variable, so that all of this code can reference it.

Then in you snapshot function, remove the 'var' in front of hashkey, so it just sets the existing variable.

Also, be sure to check if 'hashkey' has a non-blank value before sending the email.

HTH,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
firebase.database().ref('/userlist/' + uid + '/' + 'hashKey').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    var hashKey = (snapshot.val());
    console.log(hashKey)
});
```

You are creating the `var` named `hashKey` within an anonymous function then trying to access `hashKey` outside of that function.

Try the following instead:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var uid = user.uid;
var hashKey = null;

firebase.database().ref('/userlist/' + uid + '/' + 'hashKey').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    hashKey = (snapshot.val());
    console.log(hashKey)
});

... snip ...

    body: '<a href="https://nudget-72ee4.firebaseapp.com/?hashkey='+ ((hashKey == null) ? 'no-key' : hashKey) +'">Join my grocery list!</a>',

... snip ...
```